# Find the center of a circle using straight-edge and compass with given conditions.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, circles

My geometry teacher challenged me to find a way to find the center of a given circle using only ***one circle*** and ***four lines***. No tangents either. I can't seem to find a way to do this, all I've found so far are different ways of finding the diameter of the circle with one line left. I have always get one line left to draw,  and through my own constructions,there aren't any points that I could use to draw another straight line through the diameter to find the center. This is Euclidean Geometry by the way.

A simpler version of the paragraph above is to simplify the construction of Book Three Proposition one  in Euclidean Geometry so that the construction takes 4 straight lines and one circle.

Comment: draw two chords, find midpoints and draw perpendiculars to chords at midpoints, they will intersect at the center

Comment: According to my teacher, it takes two circles to find the center of a line and three circles to draw a line perpendicular. And since I'm limited to one circle, this won't work.

Comment: It takes two circles to draw perpendicular bisector to a segment

Comment: Pick an arbitrary point A on given circle. Make ONE chord AB on the given circle with A and B as endpoints. Then construct circle (A;  AB). Then where the given circle and (A; AB) intersect (besides B) mark it C. THEN continue getting the perpendicular bisectors of the two chords and where they intersect we have the center

Comment: Remember, I only get **one** circle and **four** lines. Perpendicular bisectors take two circles each and since I am limited to **one** circle, this won't work either.

Comment: Well, you asked to construct the center using Steiner's method or straightedge alone constructions. You can google it.

Comment: Will auxiliary circle(s) be needed to construct a line parallel to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually not possible. My teacher said that after a little bit of thought, he thinks it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The solution below is based on the assumption that drawing a line parallel to the other requires no auxiliary circle(s).

[image]

Step 0: Select a random point A on the given circle.

Step 1: Draw chord AB of reasonable length.

step 2: Draw $C_1$ (centered at A, radius = AB).

Step 3: Locate C where BA produced cuts $C_1$.

step 4: The two circles will meet at D. CD, when joined, will cut the given circle at E.

Step 5: Note that $\angle CDB = \angle EDB = 90^0$ because BC is the diameter of $C_1$.

Step 6: Join BE which is then the diameter of the given circle.

Step 7: Through A, draw a line parallel to CD cutting BE at F. By intercept theorem, FB = FE.

[Note:- Drawing a line parallel to a given line can be done by translating "set squares, or straight rulers" without drawing auxiliary circles. Whether the construction of such line is considered as a 1-step construction or not depends heavily on the rule of the game.]

Comment: May I ask how you drew line AF? Or how you even got point F? If step 0 is drawing line AF through the center of circle ABDE parallel to line DC, then I'm afraid this wont work for me.

Comment: @Pogitroy See the added steps and the comment.